# diff b/w submit button and anchor tag

Tags: html

I am new to this site.Started with my first question on HTML 
what is the main difference between html button type submit and anchor tag?
can both do same things then what is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

Both are different:

**[Anchor Tag](http://www.boogiejack.com/html/html-anchor-tag.html):**
The HTML anchor element is used to create a link to a resource (another web page, a file, etc.) or to a specific place within a web page.

**[Submit Button](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms12.htm):**
When a user clicks a submit button, the form is sent to the address specified in the action setting of the  tag.

**But** behaviour of both elements can be changed using [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)